# Unable to use $.after() to close a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This problem is best illustrated by example:

http://jsbin.com/lavonexuse

The desired effect is for clicking "Insert Row" to insert a full-width row after the indicated column (indicated by the class `.insertion-point`). The problem I'm running into is that instead of closing the current row first, and starting a new one, it just embeds a new row within the main row.

How do I close out the current row after any given column, make a new row, close that one, then resume showing the "data" columns?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item insertion-point">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary insert-row">Insert Row</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.pane {
  background: #999;
  height: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.insert-row').on('click', function() {
  code = '</div><!--end row--><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pane"></div></div>';

  $('.insertion-point').after(code);
});
```

EDIT:

The code string above probably should end with `<div class="row">` to re-open the row. But I tried that and it still doesn't work.

The problem here is that *visually* it looks like my solution works. Though in reality, it's creating bad HTML.

Further explanation (I think this is hard to explain). Here is what's happening, and this is NOT what I want:

[image]

I need that inserted row to be at the same level as the row it was erroneously inserted into.

### Desired HTML after jQuery manipulation

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item insertion-point">
        Data
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 pane"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Further Ramblings

Maybe, since this is Bootstrap, there's some way I can use the grid system to have the same effect.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: at no point should you have invalid html...otherwise the browser will attempt to fix it the best way it can

Comment: you need to build it as a string, and inject it all at once

Comment: @dandavis I can't do that. The columns are already rendered out. The insertion of the row *has* to come later when the user clicks a button.

Comment: but the row is already closed by the time the user clicks a button... in short, you cannot close a tag with $.after()

Comment: You shouldn't think of jQuery manipulating the HTML. It's manipulating the *DOM* using HTML markup as instructions. It doesn't create "bad HTML" -- there is no HTML anymore at that point.

Comment: what if you append the new row to the first and move all exept the first 2 to the other row?

Answer (score 1):

i worked out this four you: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37nd0Lnz/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstRow = $('.row');
    $('.insert-row').on('click', function() {
        var code = $('<div/>', {clas: 'row'}).append($('<div/>', {class: "col-sm-12 pane"})),
            row = $('<div/>', {class: 'row'}),
            items = $('.insertion-point').nextAll();
        row.append(items);        

        firstRow.after(row);
        firstRow.after(code);
    });
});
```

## Update:

after seen the nextAll function by jQuery .. this will be much faster:

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37nd0Lnz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The code below should resolve your issue. Check out the code snippet and demo:

```js
$('.insert-row').on('click', function() {
  var row = $('<div/>',{class:"row"}),
      code = '<!--end row--><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pane">New</div></div>',
      rest = $('.insertion-point').nextAll(),
      dest = $('.insertion-point').closest('.row');
  dest.after( row.append( rest ) ).after( code );
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item insertion-point">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 item">
        Data
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary insert-row">Insert Row</button>
```

Comment: $.fn.nextAll? does this get all elements after the this-element? never heared of it :) everyday learning more

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is appendTo which will append html onto the specified tag. In this case you want to append a div onto your row.

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: But I don't want to append to the row. I want to *close* the current row first, make a new one after that, then close the new row I made and reopen the first.

Comment: the "current row" is already closed...you want to inject an new div between two other div tags, which `after` actually allows

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the closing tag in the `code` variable and your code will work and be well formed

```
code = '</div><!--end row--><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pane"></div></div>';
```

should be

```
code = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pane"></div></div>';
```

Also you need to insert rows after / before other rows like so

```
$('.insert-row').on('click', function() {
    code = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pane"></div></div>';  
    $('.insertion-point').closest(".row").after(code);
});
```

The above code finds where you want to insert (which I changed to be an id selector since you want to insert after one unique element). However you want to find the closest parent element (or this one) that is a `row` so that you insert a row after that row. This way you can choose a row or a column to insert after and it will always insert a row after the closest row properly.

Lucky for you browsers are very forgiving when it comes to syntax errors in HTML. They will remove the initial closing tag (which is unnecessary) and use the rest of your HTML. But some browser may behave differently and that is what you have to be careful of.

Comment: Nope. This is not the intended result, unfortunately: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSd5F.png

Comment: maybe the row should have the `insert-row` class or the column should know it is a column and to look the parent then insert after?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new row after the first by removing the elements after the insertion point and including them in the new row.

You can't treat the DOM like a text editor when inserting html.

```
 $('.insert-row').on('click', function() { 

     var $insertEL=$('.insertion-point');
     var code = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 pane"></div></div>';
      /* create new row and append all siblings after insertion point element*/
      var $newRow=$(code).append($insertEL.nextAll());
      /* add new row to DOM*/
      $insertEL.closest('.row').after($newRow);

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cakozeyazi/1/edit?js,output)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

### Got it!

Layout solved by using Bootstrap grid, very little jQuery DOM manipulation. I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier. Sheesh. I've been coding for hours non-stop, my brain is fried.

Solution: http://jsbin.com/zopiquzore

This is correct, yes?